# How to remove query string variable from url using htaccess

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, query-string, regex-negation

my website has dynamic pages such as

http://www.example.com/index.php?layout=category&category_name=shoes&subcategory_name=sport

I want to remove or hide query string variable from url and display as

http://www.example.com/shoes/sport

Can't write the rule QUERY_STRING with eliminating LAYOUT=CATEGORY.
Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to make sure the web-server knows what to do with the new urls (use mod_rewrite for that) and in your application you will need to make sure you create the correct (new-style) urls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)